# Roll 3 die 50 times and store each in an array and display in html

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to simulate rolling 3 die 50 times, storing each in an array, and displaying the results in a table. I also need to display the results of each instance added together. Ex on roll 1 for each I got 3+4+2 = 9. I have some code, but it won't display. I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

```
  <!--
  var array1 = new Array(50);
  var array2 = new Array(50);
  var array3 = new Array(50);
  var array4 = new Array(50);

  function roll()
  {
    var face = Math.floor( (Math.random() *6) + 1);
    return face;
  }

  for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
     array1[i] = roll();
  }

  for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
     array2[i] = roll();
  }

  for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
     array3[i] = roll();
  }

  for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
     array4[i] = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i];
  }

  //Making table
  document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')

  //Loops through array object and writes values in appropriate table cells
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    document.write('<tr>')
    document.write('<td>' + i + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + array1[i] + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + array2[i] + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + array3[i] + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + array4[i] + '</td>');
    document.write('</tr>')
  }

  document.write('</table>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `array` is not defined in each of the `for` statements. Change them accordingly:

```
for( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    array1[i] = roll();
}

for( var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
{
    array2[i] = roll();
}

for( var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++)
{
    array3[i] = roll();
}

for( var i = 0; i < array4.length; i++)
{
    array4[i] = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i];
}
```

Also, you're missing a bunch of semicolons in your code. Here's a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwxu9/)** of your implementation.

Reading your browser's developer tool's console will have helped you notice the error in question.

Here's another way to possibly implement it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwxu9/1/)

I had fun with this, and made a more generalized version for many dice: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwxu9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in `for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` each time. replace them with `for( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)`, `for( var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)`, `for( var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++)` and `for( var i = 0; i < array4.length; i++)`

Comment: Do you mean adding this: `document.write('<td>' +(array1[i]+array2[i]+array3[i]+array4[i]) + '</td>');` after the line `document.write('<td>' + array4[i] + '</td>');` ?